# why null reference exception in List<decimal>

Tags: c#, list, decimal, nullreferenceexception

i have a problem, i created an object in C# like this:

```
public class logis
        {
            public string codigo { get; set; }
            public List<decimal> Necesidades { get; set; }
            decimal SumaNecesidades{get;set;}
        }
```

then i do something like this:

```
logisva logi = new logis();
logi.codigo = oDataReader.GetValue(0).ToString();
logi.Necesidades.Add(0);
```

But when i execute my code i get a null reference exception error. `Object reference not set to an instance of an object.` on the last line `logi.Necesidades.Add(0);`

Any idea why i get this error?

Comment: `logi.Necesidades` is null.  You need to initialize it somewhere - either in the getter or in a constructor.

Comment: Or with an auto-property initializer. C# 6 has been around for a while, and IMO unless there's a specific target version, we should start using its features already :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In [C# the properties](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x9fsa0sw.aspx) do not initialize/create the `List<ofType>` object automatically. You need to create the list explicitely:

```
public class logis
{
    public string codigo { get; set; }
    public List<decimal> Necesidades { get; set; }
    decimal SumaNecesidades{get;set;}

    public logis() 
    { 
        this.Necesidades = new List<decimal>(); 
    }
}
```

Another option is to create the list in the getter resp. setter (so to say your own *lazy initialization*, downside - introduces more code, advantage no need to override every contructor):

```
public class logis
{
    public string codigo { get; set; }
    decimal SumaNecesidades{get;set;}

    private List<decimal> necesidades = null;
    private void initNecesidades() 
    {
        if (this.necesidades == null) 
        { 
            this.necesidades = new List<decimal>(); 
        }
    }
    public List<decimal> Necesidades 
    { 
        get
        {
            this.initNecesidades();
            return this.necesidades;
        }
        set
        {
            this.initNecesidades();
            this.necesidades = value;
        }
    }
}
```

Yet another option would be to use the new C# 6.0 features (if it is an option to use/already using the latest .NET Framework version) as already suggested in the comments by @Jcl:

```
public List<decimal> Necesidades { get; set; } = new List<decimal>()
```

Comment: Ohh, yes you are right i am not thinkinking on this, Thanks

Comment: If using C# 6, I'd use: `public List<decimal> Necesidades { get; set; } = new List<decimal>()` and wouldn't pollute my constructor :-)

Comment: Note (about latest edit) that most C# 6 features don't need the latest framework versions, they just need a recent compiler. I haven't tested it, but I'm sure autoproperty initializers would work on .NET 3.5... possibly 2.0 too

Comment: Also, your "lazy" initializer could be rewritten (without the need for C#6.0 even) as `get { return (necesidades ?? necesidades = new List<decimal>()); } set { necesidades = value; }`, no need for the extra method and it's not a lot of code either.